# Delay in performing segue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have used AMSideMenu in my project and performing segue(from navigation bar button and UIButton) to another view controller from home screen is very slow. Any idea why is it so?

I have used the following code in Appdelegate.m

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    container.panMode = MFSideMenuPanModeNone;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
    [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
    [container setRightMenuViewController:nil];
    [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: do you mean sidemenu opening slowly?

Comment: no.. i have two button in my home view controller.one UiButton and Navigation Bar Button. it seems very slow in performing segue from these buutons

Comment: please help me get rid of these problem

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why is it so?

Make sure you don't have "slow animations" turned on in the simulator by accident. It's the first item under the Debug menu:

[image: debug menu]

Comment: It is not because of that.. i am running my app in my phone.But everything except that button works fine(without delay).